# How can I bind-mount Magento 2 files from Docker using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, magento

I need to be able to locally develop on Magento 2 (Adobe Commerce) using Docker. I am able to spin up an instance of Magento 2 using the following steps:

1. In the terminal, run the following command:  `curl -k https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/containers/main/bitnami/magento/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml`
2. In the terminal, run the following command:  `docker-compose up -d`  This will start the process of brining in the necessary files to run Magento 2.
3. In your browser, enter in “localhost:80”

Below is the docker-compose.yml file that I am using:

==================================================

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.4
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_magento
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_magento
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  magento:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/magento:2
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      - MAGENTO_HOST=localhost
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_USER=bn_magento
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_magento
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_NUMBER=9200
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'magento_data:/bitnami/magento'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/elasticsearch:7
    volumes:
      - 'elasticsearch_data:/bitnami/elasticsearch/data'
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  magento_data:
    driver: local
  elasticsearch_data:
    driver: local
```

======================================================

This gets me my local instance of Magento 2.  However, I can't work with the files as they are not being included into the folder where I have the docker-compose.yml file.  I know it has something to do with a bind-mount but I can't figure out how to go about it.

I've been working on this for weeks and just haven't found the finishing touch.

I tried finding a docker-compose.yml file that has the proper configuration to bring in the Magento 2 files into my working directory but I haven't found anything and any attempts I've had at writing in my own bind-mounts to the docker-compose.yml file have not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attention, before performing these actions, please save your changes so that you can later copy them to the Magento 2 files folder.**

To make Magento 2 files visible, you need to change the path to the 'magento_data' folder to:

```
volumes:
- './magento_data:/bitnami/magento'
```

To do this, please edit the 'docker-compose.yml' file

```
    version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.4
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_magento
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_magento
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  magento:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/magento:2
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      - MAGENTO_HOST=localhost
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_USER=bn_magento
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_magento
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_NUMBER=9200
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - './magento_data:/bitnami/magento'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/elasticsearch:7
    volumes:
      - 'elasticsearch_data:/bitnami/elasticsearch/data'
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  magento_data:
    driver: local
  elasticsearch_data:
    driver: local
```

Changes in docker-compose.yml compared to the original:

[image]

After modifying the path in the docker-compose.yml file, rebuild the containers using the following command:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

A folder named "magento_data" has appeared next to the docker-compose.yml file, where the files for Magento 2 are stored:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @byalexes !  I was so close yet so far off.